# Why is this List<>.IndexOf code so much faster than the List[i] and manual compare?

Tags: c#, performance, indexof

I'm running AQTime on this piece of code, I found that .IndexOf takes 16% of the time vs close to 80% for the other piece...  They appear to use the same IsEqual and other routines.  Called 116,000 times inserting 30,000 items.  None of the List<> objects gets over 200 elements.  (I may be using AQTime incorrectly, I'm looking into this)

```
class PointD : IEquatable<PointD>
{
    public double X, Y, Z;

    bool IEquatable<PointD>.Equals(PointD other)
    {
        return ((X == other.X) && (Y == other.Y) && (Z == other.Z));
    }
}

class PerfTest
{
    readonly List<PointD> _pCoord3Points = new List<PointD>();
    public int NewPoints;
    public int TotalPoints;

    public PerfTest()
    {
        NewPoints = 0;
        TotalPoints = 0;
    }
    public int CheckPointIndexOf(PointD pt)
    {
        int retIndex = _pCoord3Points.IndexOf(pt);
        if (retIndex < 0)
        {
            _pCoord3Points.Add(pt);
            NewPoints++;
        }
        TotalPoints++;
        return retIndex;    
    }

    public int CheckPointForBreak(PointD pt)
    {
        int retIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < _pCoord3Points.Count; i++)
        {
            PointD otherPt = _pCoord3Points[i];
            if ((pt.X == otherPt.X) &&
                (pt.Y == otherPt.Y) &&
                (pt.Z == otherPt.Z))
            {
                retIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (retIndex == -1)
        {
            NewPoints++;
            _pCoord3Points.Add(pt);
        }
        TotalPoints++;
        return retIndex;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        const int xmax = 300;
        const int ymax = 10;
        const int zmax = 10;
        const int imax = 4;

        var test = new PerfTest();
        //test.Init();
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < imax; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xmax; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < ymax; y++)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < zmax; z++)
                    {
                        var pt = new PointD { X = x, Y = y, Z = z };
                        test.CheckPointIndexOf(pt);
                    }
                }
            }

        } 
        sw.Stop();
        string output = string.Format("Total: {0:0} New: {1:0} IndexOf: ", test.TotalPoints, test.NewPoints);
        Console.Write(output);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

        test = new PerfTest();
        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < imax; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xmax; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < ymax; y++)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < zmax; z++)
                    {
                        var pt = new PointD { X = x, Y = y, Z = z };
                        test.CheckPointForBreak(pt);
                    }
                }
            }

        } 
        sw.Stop();
        output = string.Format("Total: {0:0} New: {1:0} PointD[] ", test.TotalPoints, test.NewPoints);
        Console.Write(output);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is really `IndexOf` faster? When I tried to reproduce `IndexOf` was significantly slower, and I assume Jon's speculation about boxing is correct.

Comment: I'm getting the exact opposite result, IndexOf is 20 times slower when PointD is a struct.  The Equals() method of a struct is not cheap.  Post a *real* verifiable example.

Comment: Ah, if IndexOf is faster on your machine but not with anyone else's, it's probably because of your profiler. A lot of profilers don't equally penalize code that they can't poke around in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I made the following assumptions:

- `PointD` is a struct
- `IndexOf` is indeed slower than manually iterating the list

You can speed up `IndexOf` by implementing the `IEquatable<T>` interface:

```
struct PointD : IEquatable<PointD>
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Z;

    public bool Equals(PointD other)
    {
        return (this.X == other.X) &&
                (this.Y == other.Y) &&
                (this.Z == other.Z);
    }
}
```

Without implementing the `IEquatable<T>` interface, `IndexOf` will compare the two `PointD` elements using `ValueType.Equals(object other)` which involves expensive boxing operations.

The documentation of the `IEquatable<T>` interface states:

> The `IEquatable<T>` interface is used by generic collection objects such as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `List<T>`, and `LinkedList<T>` when testing for equality in such methods as `Contains`, `IndexOf`, `LastIndexOf`, and `Remove`. **It should be implemented for any object that might be stored in a generic collection.**

Here is my complete benchmark code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

struct PointD 
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Z;
}

class PerfTest
{
    List<PointD> _pCoord3Points = new List<PointD>();

    int checkPointIndexOf(PointD pt)
    {
        return _pCoord3Points.IndexOf(pt);  
    }

    int checkPointForBreak(PointD pt)
    {
        int retIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < _pCoord3Points.Count; i++)
        {
            PointD otherPt = _pCoord3Points[i];
            if ((pt.X == otherPt.X) &&
                (pt.Y == otherPt.Y) &&
                (pt.Z == otherPt.Z))
                retIndex = i;
            break;
        }
        return retIndex;
    }

    void init()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
                {
                    PointD pt = new PointD() { X = x, Y = y, Z = z };
                    _pCoord3Points.Add(pt);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PerfTest test = new PerfTest();
        test.init();
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
                {
                    PointD pt = new PointD() { X = x, Y = y, Z = z };
                    test.checkPointIndexOf(pt);
                }
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
                {
                    PointD pt = new PointD() { X = x, Y = y, Z = z };
                    test.checkPointForBreak(pt);
                }
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

On Windows 7, x64, .NET 4.0 x64 build I get the following timings (approx):

```
IndexOf:  00:00:04.8096623
For Loop: 00:00:00.0014203
```

When turning `PointD` into a `class` the timings change to

```
IndexOf:  00:00:01.0703627
For Loop: 00:00:00.0014190
```

When using a `struct PointD` implementing  `IEquatable<PointD>` I get more "similar" results, but `IndexOf` is still slower (there is no significant difference when using a `class` now):

```
IndexOf:  00:00:00.3904615
For Loop: 00:00:00.0015218
```

Comment: @0xA3: Could you call `List<PointD>.IndexOf` once before you start the stop-watch to eliminate the JIT cost + one-time initialization (static constructor of `EqualityComparer<PointD>` to determine the right comparer etc) that happens under the hood? Not that I would consider it would matter, considering the order of magnitude difference we are seeing.

Comment: @Ani: Yes, you are correct that the benchmark is not accurate with respect to JIT overhead. But I decided to neglect the effect. In fact, if you warm up first, you will see that the JIT overhead for the for loop is more significant which seems reasonable as `List<T>.IndexOf` is contained in the native image of mscorlib.dll.

Comment: it ends up IndexOf 8.08... and [] 10.018...  that is my question why?  Thanks for all the work on your current answer

Comment: When I changed from struct to class that changed it.  Got It.  again thanks

Answer (score 4):

Normally, before you access an array element, it checks to make sure that the index is >= 0 and < length -- so that you don't read or overwrite memory that doesn't belong to you. Among other things, it eliminates a slew of severe security flaws called [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Needless to say, that impedes performance if you have very little code within your loop. To lessen this problem, the JIT compiler optimizes for-loops of the form `for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) { array[i]; }` -- that is, any loop that accesses all the indices of an array from 0 to length - 1. It omits the bounds checking for this case. (The optimization fails if you access things like array[i + 1], for the reason that you might step over the bounds.)

Unfortunately this only works with arrays, not with List<>s. So your latter code will not be optimized.

But since a List<> internally contains an array, and List.IndexOf() uses a loop to access each value in the array directly, it can be optimized.

By the way, it's better to say `for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) { }` than it is to say `int length = array.Length; for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) { }` -- because it can't be sure that `length` really is the length of the array.

Edit: looking at the IndexOf code using Reflector, the loop will indeed optimize, but as the other people here have mentioned, it calls Equals() -- which requires a [vtable lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vtable) and various sanity checks. So in this case, IndexOf might in fact be slower when you're not running it with a profiler.

The disassembled code:

```
internal virtual int IndexOf(T[] array, T value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    int num = startIndex + count;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (this.Equals(array[i], value))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Crazy random knowledge of .NET there!

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of `_pCoord3Points`? If the element type is a value type which only overrides `Equals(object)` then it's possible that `IndexOf` is repeatedly boxing values to check for equality. That *might* explain it. It's really just guesswork at this point though... if you could provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, that would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: But if `IndexOf` involved boxing then it should be slower, not faster as the OP claims, shouldn't it?

Comment: Indeed, Jon, you seem to be right. I measured and `IndexOf` is significantly slower (in my measurement around factor 1000) for value types and still around a factor of 100 slower for reference types.