# Sort a list from another list IDs

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, collections

I have a list with some identifiers like this:

```
List<long> docIds = new List<long>() { 6, 1, 4, 7, 2 };
```

Morover, I have another list of `<T>` items, which are represented by the ids described above.

```
List<T> docs = GetDocsFromDb(...)
```

I need to keep the same order in both collections, so that the items in `List<T>` must be in the same position than in the first one (due to search engine scoring reasons). And this process cannot be done in the `GetDocsFromDb()` function.

If necessary, it's possible to change the second list into some other structure (`Dictionary<long, T>` for example), but I'd prefer not to change it.

Is there any simple and efficient way to do this "ordenation depending on some IDs" with LINQ?

Comment: are you assured that every `docId` occurs exactly once in `docs`, what property will hold the `Id` or will a selector `Func<T, long>` be required?

Comment: Does the first list represent a "master list"? Another words, will the second list be a subset representing a portion (or the entirety) of the first list?

Answer (score 479, accepted):

```
docs = docs.OrderBy(d => docsIds.IndexOf(d.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: @Kaf thats why I upvoted too, does rely on knowing the document ID property is called `Id`. Its not specified in the question.

Comment: @BorjaLópez, a quick note. You mention efficiency in your question. `IndexOf` is perfectly acceptable for your example and nice and simple. If you had a lot of data my answer might be better suited. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663014/why-is-this-list-indexof-code-so-much-faster-than-the-listi-and-manual-compa

Comment: I've benchmarked this method and the one with the Dictionary (see below) and it's almost twice as fast.

Comment: @DenysDenysenko Fantastic. Thanks so much; exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: does not work if you have elements in docs that do not have ids in the ordering list

Comment: Quite inefficient  - IndexOf is being called for every element in the source collection and OrderBy has to order the elements. The solution by @Jodrell is much faster.

Comment: @DanHunex if you need the non existing ids to appear at the end of the list you can do: 
.OrderBy(d=> {
                    var index = docIds.IndexOf(d.Id);
                    if (index == -1) index = docIds.Count;
                    return index;
                })

Answer (score 52):

Since you don't specify `T`,

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBySequence<T, TId>(
       this IEnumerable<T> source,
       IEnumerable<TId> order,
       Func<T, TId> idSelector)
{
    var lookup = source.ToDictionary(idSelector, t => t);
    foreach (var id in order)
    {
        yield return lookup[id];
    }
}
```

Is a generic extension for what you want.

You could use the extension like this perhaps,

```
var orderDocs = docs.OrderBySequence(docIds, doc => doc.Id);
```

---

A safer version might be

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBySequence<T, TId>(
       this IEnumerable<T> source,
       IEnumerable<TId> order,
       Func<T, TId> idSelector)
{
    var lookup = source.ToLookup(idSelector, t => t);
    foreach (var id in order)
    {
        foreach (var t in lookup[id])
        {
           yield return t;
        }
    }
}
```

which will work if `source` does not zip exactly with `order`.

Comment: I used this solution and it worked. Just that, i had to make the method static and the class static.

Comment: 10 years old (almost) and still a wonderful solution. tnx (likewise had to embed in a static helper class but does offer great reuse)

Comment: @jimtollan, Nice of you to say so. I guess it is also a good reflection on Stack Overflow. You should bear in mind that `Join` works too. [Sort a list from another list IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55650341)

Comment: +1 more versatile, e.g : `EmployeeList.OrderBySequence(HospitalList.OrderBy(h => h.Position).Select(h => h.Id), e => e.HospitalId)` gives : employees order by their hospital itself order by its position

Answer (score 32):

Jodrell's answer is best, but actually he reimplemented `System.Linq.Enumerable.Join`. Join also uses Lookup and keeps ordering of source.

```cs
    docIds.Join(
      docs,
      i => i,
      d => d.Id,
      (i, d) => d);
```

Comment: That is the answer we are looking for

Comment: This just proves that Join is too difficult to understand since everyone agreed that rewriting it was easier.

Answer (score -4):

One simple approach is to zip with the ordering sequence:

```
List<T> docs = GetDocsFromDb(...).Zip(docIds, Tuple.Create)
               .OrderBy(x => x.Item2).Select(x => x.Item1).ToList();
```

Comment: Because `Zip` combines each index (into a Tuple) with the document in the same position in the corresponding list. Then the OrderBy sorts the Tuples by the index part and then the select digs our just the docs from the now ordered list.

Comment: but, the result of GetDocsFromDb is unordered so you'll be creating Tuples where `Item1` is unrelated to `Item2`.

Comment: I think this will produce incorrect results since ordering performing uppon id and not the index.