# How to filter with a list of keywords on a DBSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have in my Controller :

```cs
var query = _context.Jobs.Where(x => x.Category.Equals(filterParams.Category) ||
filterParams.Query.Any(val => x.Title.Contains(val)));
```

And this is the `FilterParams` class

```cs
    public class FilterParams
    {
        public string[] Query { get; set; }
        public CategoryEnum Category { get; set; }
    }
```

The filter on the `Category` works fine, but the `Title` part doesn't.
I tried a bunch of different ways but it never gives me the expected behavior which is:

Given the following `filterParams.Query` (string[]) : ['FOO', 'BAR']
I want it to return entities with title such as: foo alice bar ; foo bar bob

How can we filter based on an array ?

The error I get is :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'val => EntityShaperExpression: 
    ynyn_be.Models.Job
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.Title.Contains(val)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

I don't understand because, after the filters, I'm doing my `Skip()` and `Take()` with a `ToListAsync`, so why is it asking me to do it again ? I'm confused.

Comment: What is the database engine you are using?

Comment: Well this makes perfect sense because you need to think how could this be translated to Sql. You could write this query but it would require some native sql that could be dependent on your sql provider.

Comment: Sounds like you need `LIKE '%xxx%'`. This will get you like on one value  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq But then seem you need to like on multiple values. For that either use Expression Trees or Linq.Dynamic

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server
I don't mind writing the query, I was just wondering if I could use some built-in stuff instead.
Thanks i'll take a look over Expression Trees and Linq Dynamic

Comment: @T.S. I think PostgreSQL could do this out of the box since they support array parameters and operators I don't think server has something like that.

Comment: @MA-Moustache there is a trick to pass lists in SQL Server using the select union trick I talked about here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210085/6330636

Comment: @MA-Moustache just remember to use parameters in the selection if the value is from the client.

Comment: How does entity framework even setup the database with `string[]` ? to my knowledge there is no array type in a sql Server?

Comment: @RandRandom in my database, the title is a simple string. But if my user types for example: "Java Senior", I want to return entities with a title that contains Java AND Senior.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which may be temporary until I find a cleaner way of doing it, still sharing it if it can help others

```cs
                IQueryable<Job> query = _context.Jobs;

                if (filterParams.Category != null)
                {
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Category.Equals(filterParams.Category));
                } 

                foreach (var key in filterParams.Query)
                {
                    query = query.Where(x => 
                        x.Title.ToLower().Contains(key) ||
                        x.Description.ToLower().Contains(key));
                }
```

I just iterate over my array of keywords and add them to my `IQueryable`.