# C# Linq - Order an IEnumerable based off the order of another IEnumerable's items

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to make an extension method and am having some difficulty with this case, examples:

```
IEnumerable<string> list1 = // { "A", "B", "C" }
IEnumerable<string> list2 = // { "B", "D" }
IEnumerable<string> list3 = // { "D", "A", "C". "B" } 

list1.OrderByEnumerable(list3) -> // { "A", "C", "B" }
list2.OrderByEnumerable(list3) -> // { "D", "B" }
```

I have been trying something along the lines of:

```
static IEnumerable<T> OrderByEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, IEnumerable<string> data2)
{
    return data.Zip(data2, (x, y) => //
}
```

but I quickly realized I need some way to iterate through the enumerables to find out of I need to "skip" a value and somehow. Any ideas or pointers in the right direction?

Comment: What is expected result in case when item not exists in `list3`?

Comment: If you are willing to work with lists, instead of IEnumerable, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15275394/6741868) is a one line answer which might help you.

Comment: @Fabio yes your question is valid and unless or until the OP answers it, it is hard to post an answer because I do not know what to do in that case either so I am holding off. Better yet, I am going to go to sleep :)

Comment: Sorry, list 3 is the list that is going to be the 'order' list1 and list2 must follow, if list3 has a object not in list1 or list2, it is skipped

Comment: So if list 1 or 2 has something list 3 doesnt have, probably should break or return original list, if list 3 has something 1 or 2 doesnt have, it is skipped. As long as 1 and 2 follow the ordering pattern set forth by 3 for all matching items

Answer (score 3):

In looking at this example:

```
list1.OrderByEnumerable(list3) -> // { "A", "C", "B" }
```

...I can't help but notice that the list is exactly the same as `list3` with items removed if they do not appear in `list1`.

So maybe you just need to intersect and be done:

```
list3.Intersect(list1) -> // { "A", "C", "B" }
```

Of course it is always possible that `list1` contains some items that aren't in `list3`, but you didn't specify a requirement in that case.  I guess you could just add them to the end:

```
list3.Intersect(list1).Union(list1.Except(list3)); -> // { "A", "C", "B" }
```

This is equivalent to what you are attempting, without any need to `Zip` or `Join` anything.

Comment: `list3.Intersect(list1)` will produce `{ "A", "B", "C" }` not `{ "A", "C", "B" }`. This is not what the question is asking but the OP has accepted it so perhaps the question is wrong.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, in case where `{ "D", "A", "C". "B" }` ordered by `{ "A", "B", "C" }` result should be `{ "A", "B", "C" }`, only mystery is still what to do when `"D"` not exists in "order" collection

Comment: I misunderstood, Both of you are correct in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data,
                                                       IEnumerable<T> data2)
{
    return data.Except(data2).Any() ? data : data2.Join(data, _ => _, _ => _, (_, __) => _);
}
```