# Sort items arbitrarily using external priority list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of unique items like this:

```
List<Animals> ItemList = Cat, Dog, Bird, ...
```

I'm trying to sort it using a external priority list like this:

```
List<Animals> PriorityList = Dog, Cat, Bird, ...
```

I found out I can sort the items correctly in this way:

```
ItemList.OrderBy(i => i == Dog).ThenBy(i => i.Cat).ThenBy(i => i.Bird)...
```

But the scalability of this approach is terribly bad; do someone has an idea how to do this using LINQ and the PriorityList?

Comment: Order by their index in the other list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a list from another list IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275269/sort-a-list-from-another-list-ids)

Comment: create an array of the strings and then sort byte the index number of the item.  List<string> PriorityList = new List<string() { Cat, Dog, Bird }; ItemList.OrderBy(i => PriorityList.IndexOf(i));

Comment: Wow, that's great guys. I was searching for the words to explain it and this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can order the items by their index in the other list:

```
var orderedList = ItemList.OrderBy(i => PriorityList.IndexOf(i)).ToList();
```

However, if an item happens to *not* be in the priority list at all, then that item will come first, because `IndexOf` will return `-1` for an item that doesn't exist. If you'd rather have them come last, then you can check if the list contains the item first, and if it doesn't, return a larger number, like `int.MaxValue` or `PriorityList.Count`:

```
var ordered = items
    .OrderBy(i => priorities.Contains(i) ? priorities.IndexOf(i) : int.MaxValue)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I was not aware of this. I will implement it right now.

Answer (score 1):

If the cost of looking up the priority is significant (remember there are *O(n* log *n)* comparisons, with two look-ups per comparison), then doing that lookup once is an option. Tuples avoid the need to create a type to hold the intermediate result.

```
var ordered = ItemList
               .Select(i => (item: i, priority: PriorityList.IndexOf(i))
               .OrderBy(i => i.priority)
               .Select(i => i.item)
               .ToList();
```

(I use `ToList` here to avoid running the sort many times if the result is enumerated multiple times.)

Comment: I didn't mention it but in my case the list will be never longer than 20-30 items, then in my case the readability of the first answer would be a better trade-off. Anyway, in case I need to reuse this code in the future it's nice to be aware of this, thanks.