# Is there a way to look for a list of ids in a list of parent object type?

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections

First of all, apologies if my title is not descriptive enough. Here is my problem.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of type Person, whereby

```
var people = new List<Person>
{  
   new Person(1, "John"),
   new Person(2, "George"),
   new Person(3, "Ann"),
   new Person(4, "Mary")
}
```

And now I have

```
var sortedIds = new List<int> {4, 2, 3, 1};
```

So I want to end up with a `List<Person>` that would look like

```
(4, "Mary"),
(2, "George"),
(3, "Ann"),
(1, "John")
```

i.e. using the order of the int list. How can I go from one to the other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Several good answers: [Sort a list from another list IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275269/sort-a-list-from-another-list-ids)

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so so much.

Comment: Be aware that this is `O(n^2)`. For small lists this is perfect, but for large ones I would add the sortedIds to a dictionary with the Id as key and the order number as value.