# C# LINQ OrderBy values from another List(IEnumerable)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's imagine we have a list of strings `var listA = new List<string> {"B", "C", "A"}`, and it is sorted in the desired manner.
And, there is an object defined like:

```
public class Sample {
   public string Letter {get;set;} // "A","B","C","D","#"
   public string Number {get;set;} // not relevant
}
```

Also, there is another list, `List<Sample> listB`, and I want to sort it in a way that first comes objects with Letter values "B", then "C" and on the end, "A", so to respect same order as it is in the listA.  Any ideas? :)

EDIT:
Letter property can have a wider range of characters, unlike listA which can have just those 3. Expected order "B","C", "A"..."all the rest, order not relevant"

Comment: so what's expected order of out ranged ones? this should be well defined

Comment: i've edited the question, please take a look

Answer (score 2):

Assume value of `Letter` are within `listA`. It's worth considering redesigning the algorithm if the assumption is false. And it may depend on requirement of expected order the out of range ones.

```cs
   var sortedSamples = listB.OrderBy(x=>listA.IndexOf(x.Letter));
```

For better performance, cache the orders into a dictionary:

```cs
   var orders = new Dictionary<string, int>();
   for (int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
   {
      orders.Add(listA[i], i);
   }
   var sortedSamples = listB.OrderBy(x=>orders[x.Letter]);
```

If possible values range of `Letter` is much smaller than `listA`, then better consturct `orders` like this:

```cs
   foreach (string letter in listB.Select(x=>x.Letter))
   {
      orders.Add(letter, listA.IndexOf(letter));
   }
```

---

*Update*

If `letters`' range are out of `listA`, and since OP want the out ones to be at the end:

```cs
   var orders = new Dictionary<string, int>();
   for (int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
   {
      orders.Add(listA[i], i);
   }
   int lastIndex = listA.Count;
   foreach (string letter in listB.Select(x=>x.Letter)
                                  .Distinct().Except(listA))
   {
      orders.Add(letter, lastIndex);
   }
```

Comment: Be advised that this has O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: thank. updated with caching solution.

Comment: can you suggest why does [this similiar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15275394/1518100) (same time complexity) got hundreds of stars? thanks for your upvotes ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to mention one important thing in my case - Letter property might contain characters that are not in the listA, something like "D" for example, and in the first solution it might happen we get OutOfRangeException

Comment: so what's expected order of out ranged ones? this should be well defined.

Comment: i've edited the question, please take a look

Comment: see my updated code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a specific implementation of the method body of [@nannanas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71238632/c-sharp-linq-orderby-values-from-another-listienumerable#answer-71239179), which also works when `listA` does not contain all letters present in `listB`:

```csharp
listB = listA.Union(listB.Select(entry => entry.Letter))
    .Join(listB,
         letter => letter,
         sample => sample.Letter,
         ( _, sample ) => sample)
    .ToList();
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3DwDBH).

---

#### Walk-through

Let's say we have the following lists:

```csharp
var listA = new List<string> { "B", "C", "A" };

var listB = new List<Sample>
{
    new Sample { Letter = "E", Number = "1" },
    new Sample { Letter = "C", Number = "2" },
    new Sample { Letter = "A", Number = "3" },
    new Sample { Letter = "B", Number = "4" },
    new Sample { Letter = "D", Number = "5" }
};
```

##### The first line:

`listB.Select(entry => entry.Letter)` will extract each `Letter` value in `listB`, resulting in:

> { "E", "C", "A", "B", "D" }

`listA.Union(listB.Select(entry => entry.Letter))` uses [.Union()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-6.0) to create the [set union](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Union.html) of `listA` and `listB`'s `Letter` values by first yielding each distinct item in the set of `listA` (`"B", "C", "A"`), then yielding each distinct item in the set of `Letter`s from `listB` *that are not present in `listA`* (`"E", "D"`); resulting in:

> { "B", "C", "A", "E", "D" }

We now have the order of the letters that we want `listB` to reflect: First, the order given by `listA`, then, the remaning letters present in `listB`.

##### The .Join() operation

[.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-6.0) associates an **outer sequence** with an **inner sequence** based on association keys defined by a **key selector** for each **sequence**; and then returns an `IEnumerable<T>` from the associations based on the **result selector**:

```csharp
outerSequence.Join(innerSequence,
    outerItem => /*  */, // key selector (outerItem is a string)
    innerItem => /*  */, // key selector (innerItem is a Sample)
    ( associatedOuterItem, associatedInnerItem ) => /*  */) // result selector
```

`{ "B", "C", "A", "E", "D" }` is thereby the **outer sequence** in the `.Join()` operation. The **inner sequence** of the `.Join()` operation is `listB`. By using `.Join()`, we can associate items in the **outer sequence** with items in the **inner sequence** by the sequences' matching **key selectors**.

For the **outer sequence**, we define the **key selector** as being the whole item:

```csharp
letter => letter // alternatively: outerItem => outerItem
```

As an example, the two first items in the **outer sequence** are `"B"` and `"C"`; so, the association key for the first two items in the **outer sequence** are `"B"` and `"C"`.

For the **inner sequence**, we define the **key selector** as being the `Letter` property of the `Sample` object:

```csharp
sample => sample.Letter // alternatively: innerItem => innerItem.Letter
```

As an example, the two first items in the **inner sequence** are `Sample { Letter = "E", Number = "1" }` and `Sample { Letter = "C", Number = "2" }`; so, the association key for the first two items in the **inner sequence** are each item's `Letter` value: `"E"` and `"C"`.

Hence, the full set of **key selectors** for the **outer** and **inner sequences** are, respectively:

> { "B", "C", "A", "E", "D" }
> { "E", "C", "A", "B", "D" }

The `.Join()` operation now associates the items in each **sequence** based on the **key selectors**. The associations keep the order provided by the **outer sequence**, and can be illustrated as follows:

| Item from outer sequence | Item from inner sequence |
| --- | --- |
| `"B"` | `Sample { Letter = "B", Number = "4" }` |
| `"C"` | `Sample { Letter = "C", Number = "2" }` |
| `"A"` | `Sample { Letter = "A", Number = "3" }` |
| `"E"` | `Sample { Letter = "E", Number = "1" }` |
| `"D"` | `Sample { Letter = "D", Number = "5" }` |

The last `.Join()` input parameter is the **result selector**, which defines what should be returned from each association. Seeing as we only need the item from the **inner sequence**, we specify that in the **result selector**:

```
( _, sample ) => sample
```

(The **result selector** could have been rewritten to e.g. `( letter, sample ) => sample`, but seeing as the items from the **outer sequence** (referred to as `letter`) are not of interest, I have simply discarded (`_`) that object in my example.)

Comment: but a little hard to understand and i'm curious: what step sorted, without a `OrderBy`?

Comment: @LeiYang True! I am short on time at the moment, but have added an initial explanation. Will add an extended explanation when I have the time.

Comment: Updated with further explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You should using something like this

```
            var listA = new List<string> { "B", "C", "A" };
            var listB = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
            listB = listB.OrderBy(d => listA.IndexOf(d)).ToList();
            // listB: "B", "C", "A"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this extension which also supports comparing the entries in the lists by a specific property (e.g. id instead of reference)

```
public static IEnumerable<TFirst> OrderBy<TFirst, TSecond, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TKey> firstKeySelector, Func<TSecond, TKey> secondKeySelector) =>
            second
                .Join(
                    first,
                    secondKeySelector,
                    firstKeySelector,
                    (_, firstItem) => firstItem);
```

this will sort the items in `second` the same way as they are already sorted in `first` comparing them using both key selectors.

Be aware that this only works if ALL the keys in `first` are also present in `second`.